# DataGridView with different cell types like the Property Grid

Tags: c#, .net, datagridview

Is it possible to configure the DataGridView in .NET to behave like the Property Grid? I mean to display different styles of cells per row? All I can do so far is to change the type per column.

I do have a list of Parameter Objects, some of them are single numeric values and some are arrays. So I would like to display all them in a DataGridView. The scalar values should be editable in the list, but for arrays I would like to display a link "Edit" in the same cell.

Comment: http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/63ddb457-f769-44db-87cc-9e88e74929e8/how-to-host-different-controls-in-the-same-column-in-datagridview-control?forum=winformsdesigner - I think here is your answer.

Comment: Thank you! This is exactly what I need. I'm wondering I couldn't find it.. And I was trying to create some custom cells, but the solution in your link is so much simpler...

Answer (score 0):

if you want to add comboBox columns dynamically to your datagridview you could use the following code:

```
Dim GridOptions() As String = {"Test1", "Test2", "Test3"}
Dim DropDownCol As New DataGridViewComboBoxColumn
DropDownCol.DataSource = GridOptions
DataGridView1.Columns.Add(DropDownCol)
```